# How can I change the dropdown content

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I am trying to do a dropdown filter content in ASP.NET MVC. I want the dropdown to show the three Graduation Status (Graduated, Pass, Failed) and that when I select one it will only show the student of the selected status!

Here a screenshot of what I am seeing right now:

[image: Index page with dropdown]

Controller:

```
ViewBag.GraduationStatus = new SelectList(db.Graduated_Students, "Graduated Status");

var graduates = db.Graduated_Students.Where(student => student.GraduationStatus != null);
return View(graduates.ToList());
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DropDownList("GraduationStatus", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            </th>
            <th>
                <input type="submit" value="Filter by graduation Status" />
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

Model :

```
namespace CodeboxxSchoolPortal
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Graduated_Students
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int CohortId { get; set; }
        public string GraduationStatus { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string ContractStatus { get; set; }
        public string DepositStatus { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> PartnerId { get; set; }
        public string PartnerName { get; set; }


            public List<SelectListItem> GraduationStatusList = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                 new SelectListItem { Value="Graduated", Text="Graduated" },
                 new SelectListItem { Value ="Pass", Text="Pass" },
                 new SelectListItem { Value ="Failed", Text="Failed" }
            };

        public class SelectListItem
        {
            public string Value { get; set; }
            public string Text { get; set; }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at this demo and let me know if it suffices to your needs: https://dotnetfiddle.net/OBg7Rp

Comment: Did my example help you out?

Comment: Thanks for you help, sorry for the late asnwer! I'm trying to make it work at the moment but it still won't because of this error in the view :                    'IEnumerable<Graduated_Students>' does not contain a definition for 'GraduationStatus' and no accessible extension method 'GraduationStatus' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<Graduated_Students>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: This is happening because the Model you are sending to your View does not have the proper binding to GraduationStatus. If you will see my example, the Model values are binded to the values and then they are being redndered on the View using @DropDownListFor. Basically my point is that you would have to bind your SelectList values in your controller and bind them correctly.

Comment: I have edited my question so that you can see my model thanks for helping!! I'm still stuck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I think you should do,

if your `Action` in the controller is `GetStudents`, and your dropdown list has values as string(Graduation status), pass it to the controller on the filter button click

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Documents(string? graduationStatus)
 {
     var graduates = db.Graduated_Students.Where(student => student.GraduationStatus == graduationStatus);
     return View(graduates.ToList());
 }
```

> Note that the `string? graduationStatus` has to be of the same type as `student.GraduationStatus` in the database
>
> Also make sure that `Html.BeginForm()` has the proper action to the controller

```
@Html.BeginForm("GetStudents", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "my_form"})
```

**EDIT:**

Change the line below to

```
@Html.DropDownList("GraduationStatus", new SelectList(ViewBag.GraduationStatus, "Value Here", "Text Here", null), "- Select -", new { @class = "form-control"})
```

Comment: Where should I put this lines of code ? @Html.BeginForm("GetStudents", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "my_form"}) Thanks for the help!!

Comment: In your view where you have `@using(Html.BeginForm())`

Comment: This is where I replaced the lines but now in my index there is nothing showing in the dropdown filter...Thanks for the help!

Comment: Pretty sure that my problem is in this line...  @Html.DropDownList("GraduationStatus", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })